# what is the difference between No Upfront Reserved Instances and on demand instances aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When trying to purchase a AWS reserved instance, I have found for no upfront,  What is the difference between it and on demand instances ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you purchase a [AWS reserved instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/?nc1=h_ls) you reserve the capacity from AWS. You know you're needing a certain capacity for 1 or 3 years so you want to reserve it and to make sure a specific instance of this type will be available for you.

The upfront fee is just a payment method. You can choose between three payment options: *All Upfront*, *Partial Upfront*, and *No Upfront*. If you choose the Partial or No Upfront payment option, the remaining balance will be due in monthly increments over the term

When you purchase a reserved instance with No Upfront free, you will pay on a monthly basis the price (this price depends on your region and instance type) wether you're using the capacity or not. This price is a discount price (from 40% up to 75%) compared to the OnDemand price for the same instance in the same region.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Fredric's answer, Reserved Instance(RI) is a commitment from AWS to reserve capacity in exchange of customer's billing commitment.

Billing can be commited as no-upfront, partial upfront or all upfront. For committing to RIs, customers get pricing discount depending upon type of RIs and tenure. Once RIs are purchased, you would be billed for those RIs irrespective of your actually utilization of RIs.  Customer cannot cancel RIs once they are purchased post 15 days of purchase. Customer can switch between instance types if RIs are convertible or sell of their RIs in marketplace in case they are planning to not use them.

Comment: RIs only provide a capacity reservation when the RI is tied to a specific availability zone.  Regional RIs don't reserve capacity, but as you indicated, all RIs are a contractual obligation.  You pay for the instance even if you have no instance matching the reservation.